# Jetty and Java Agent Don't Work Using Logging

Tags: java, jetty, aspectj, instrumentation, javaagents

I'm trying to run Jetty with java agent instrumentation.
I'm using the following command:

```
java -javaagent:%JETTY_HOME%/lib/ext/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar -jar %JETTY_HOME%/start.jar
```

It works as expected.

But, when adding a logging module to Jetty (`java -jar %JETTY_HOME%/start.jar --add-to-start log4j`) and then start the Jetty server it runs without instrumentation at all.

Note: I was able to start the agent with instrumentation when I used the full output of '--dry-run' command.

Any idea why the agent wasn't loaded when running the standard jetty startup command with a logging module?

Thanks,

Dror

Answer (score 2):

Run `java -jar start.jar --list-config` from your jetty base.

It's likely that your configuration is triggering an `--exec` call which will fork a new JVM.

The `-javaagent` command would not be passed forward to that new JVM.